# How to create custom range sliders with min and max using CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a requirement to have a range slider with min and max and 2 textboxes to show those selected values in the given design of the range slider. I tried to refer below links.
`https://jsfiddle.net/b68fp7qd/` . But no css is mentioned in that code snippet.
And in this link, `https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range` there is no tooltip and bit difference in the design and color to change.
Can anyone help to achieve this.

[image]

I have tried below code

HTML:

```
<div class="filter-container">
    <div class="filter-section">

        <div class="slider-wrapper">
            <div id="slider" class="store-slider"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row filter-row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control price-input" id="price_from">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control price-input" id="price_to">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.filter-container {
max-width: 280px;
margin: 50px auto;
background: #fff;
border-radius: 6px;
}

.filter-section {
    padding: 20px;
}

.filter-section + .filter-section {
    border-top: 1px solid #f1f3f4;
}

.slider-wrapper {
margin: 60px auto 0;
padding: 0 8px;
}

.store-slider.ui-slider {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
margin-top: 30px;
}

.store-slider .ui-slider-range {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
background: rgb(233, 236, 239);
}

.store-slider .ui-slider-handle {
top: auto;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
margin: 0;
margin-left: -10px;
border-radius: 50%;
border: none;
background: #fff;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 transparent, 0 0 2px rgba(103, 118, 125, 1), 0 4px 10px rgba(91, 111, 144, 0.3);
cursor: pointer;
}

.store-slider .ui-slider-handle:hover,
.store-slider .ui-slider-handle.ui-state-hover {
    background: #89cd20;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #75b316, 0 0 2px rgba(103, 118, 125, 0.5), 0 4px 10px rgba(91, 111, 144, 0.3);
}

.store-slider.ui-widget.ui-widget-content {
border: 1px solid rgb(206, 212, 218);
}

.ui-slider-handle:hover,
.ui-slider-handle:active,
.ui-slider-handle:focus {
outline: none;
}

.ui-slider-handle:active {
background: #89cd20;
border-color: #75b316;
}

.tippy-content {
font-size: 13px;
}

.row.filter-row {
margin-top: 15px;
margin-left: -7px;
margin-right: -8px;
}

.row.filter-row [class*="col-"] {
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 8px;
}
```

JS:

```
console.clear();

var currentValue = {
from: 1106,
to: 10000
}

var slider = $('#slider').slider({
range: true,
min: 0,
max: 11850,
values: [currentValue.from, currentValue.to],
create: function (event, ui) {
    var $slider = $(this);
    var $sliderWrapper = $slider.closest('.store-slider-wrapper');
    var $sliderHandlers = $slider.find('.ui-slider-handle');
    var $sliderHandlersMin = $sliderHandlers.eq(0);
    var $sliderHandlersMax = $sliderHandlers.eq(1);
    var $sliderRange = $slider.find('.ui-slider-range');
    var values = {
        from: currentValue.from,
        to: currentValue.to
    }

    $sliderHandlersMin.attr('title', values.from);
    $sliderHandlersMax.attr('title', values.to);
    $sliderRange
        .attr('title', values.from + ' - ' + values.to)
        .attr('data-tippy-distance', 15);;

    var tippyOptions = {
        trigger: 'manual',
        sticky: true,
        dynamicTitle: true,
        hideOnClick: false,
        arrow: true,
        arrowType: 'round',
        animation: 'fade',
        placement: 'top',
        livePlacement: false,
        flipBehavior: [],
        createPopperInstanceOnInit: true,
        appendTo: $(this).closest('.filter-section')[0],
        popperOptions: {
            modifiers: {
                // preventOverflow: {
                //     boundariesElement: $(this).closest('.filter-section')[0],
                // }
                computeStyle: {
                    gpuAcceleration: true
                }
            },
        }
    };

    tippy($sliderHandlersMin[0], tippyOptions);
    tippy($sliderHandlersMax[0], tippyOptions);
    tippy($sliderRange[0], tippyOptions);

    updateSliderTooltip($slider, values);
},
slide: function (event, ui) {
    var $slider = $(this);
    var $sliderWrapper = $slider.closest('.store-slider-wrapper');
    var values = {
        from: ui.values[0],
        to: ui.values[1]
    }

    updateSliderTooltip($slider, values, true);
}
});

function updateSliderTooltip($slider, values, updateInput) {
if (typeof updateInput === "undefined")
    var updateInput = true;

var $sliderWrapper = $slider.closest('.store-slider-wrapper');
var $sliderHandlers = $slider.find('.ui-slider-handle');
var $sliderHandlersMin = $sliderHandlers.eq(0);
var $sliderHandlersMax = $sliderHandlers.eq(1);
var $sliderRange = $slider.find('.ui-slider-range');

$sliderHandlersMin.attr('title', values.from);
$sliderHandlersMax.attr('title', values.to);
$sliderRange.attr('title', values.from + '  ' + values.to);

if (updateInput) {
    $('#price_from').val(values.from);
    $('#price_to').val(values.to);
}

setInterval(function () {
    var tooltipMinLeft = getCoords($sliderHandlersMin[0]).left;
    var tooltipMaxLeft = getCoords($sliderHandlersMax[0]).left;

    var tooltipRange = tooltipMaxLeft - tooltipMinLeft;
    var singleTooltip = tooltipRange < 80;

    if (!singleTooltip) {
        if (!$sliderHandlersMin[0]._tippy.state.visible)
            $sliderHandlersMin[0]._tippy.show(0);
        if (!$sliderHandlersMax[0]._tippy.state.visible)
            $sliderHandlersMax[0]._tippy.show(0);
        if ($sliderRange[0]._tippy.state.visible)
            $sliderRange[0]._tippy.hide(0);
    } else {
        if ($sliderHandlersMin[0]._tippy.state.visible)
            $sliderHandlersMin[0]._tippy.hide(0);
        if ($sliderHandlersMax[0]._tippy.state.visible)
            $sliderHandlersMax[0]._tippy.hide(0);
        if (!$sliderRange[0]._tippy.state.visible)
            $sliderRange[0]._tippy.show(0);
    }
}, 1);
}

function updateValues() {
var from = $('#price_from').val();
var to = $('#price_to').val();

updateSliderTooltip(slider, {
    from: from,
    to: to
}, false);

slider.slider({
    values: [from, to]
});
}

$('#price_from').on('blur', function () {
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/i, ''));

if (+$(this).val() > +$('#price_to').val()) {
    $(this).val($('#price_to').val())
}

updateValues();
});

$('#price_to').on('blur', function () {
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/gi, ''));

if (+$(this).val() < +$('#price_from').val()) {
    $(this).val($('#price_from').val())
}

updateValues();
});

function getCoords(elem) {
var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

var body = document.body;
var docEl = document.documentElement;

var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || docEl.scrollTop || body.scrollTop;
var scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || docEl.scrollLeft || body.scrollLeft;

var clientTop = docEl.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0;
var clientLeft = docEl.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0;

var top = box.top + scrollTop - clientTop;
var left = box.left + scrollLeft - clientLeft;

return { top: Math.round(top), left: Math.round(left) };
}
```

But with this I'm unable to see the slider. Design is coming as per the below image. Also the code for the tooltip is breaking and getting below console error:

> VM391:620 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getBoundingClientRect')     at getCoords (:620:20)     at :561:30

[image]

Comment: the fiddle you linked (https://jsfiddle.net/b68fp7qd/) uses Ion.RangeSlider (http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/). As you can see on their documentation, it offers options to change the "skin" (http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/skins.html). It is in fact using CSS: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.1.2/css/ion.rangeSlider.min.css which you can override to apply your custom styles

Comment: [Is this the test result you want?](https://codepen.io/mrgrump/pen/JpZNXZ)

Comment: It seems to me that you can hire a freelancer and hies will solve your "problem".

Comment: Hi @Limna， you just need to tell me if this is what you want, and I will try my best to help you solve the rest.

Comment: Please wait, I am handling this issue. Will update soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just implement it in my sample project with no error. You can modify it according your needs.

**1. Create a Slider.cshtml and define it in HomeController.**

[image]

*Slider.cshtml*

```html
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "jQuery UI range slider with tooltip tippy.js";
}
<style>
    * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #f1f3f4;
  height: 10000px
}

.filter-container {
  max-width: 280px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.filter-section {
    padding: 20px;
}

.filter-section + .filter-section {
  border-top: 1px solid #f1f3f4;
}

.slider-wrapper {
  margin: 60px auto 0;
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.store-slider.ui-slider {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.store-slider .ui-slider-range {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: rgb(233, 236, 239);
}

.store-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    top: auto;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: -10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 
        inset 0 0 0 transparent,
        0 0 2px rgba(103, 118, 125, 1), 
        0 4px 10px rgba(91, 111, 144, 0.3);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.store-slider .ui-slider-handle:hover,
.store-slider .ui-slider-handle.ui-state-hover {
    background: #89cd20;
    box-shadow: 
        inset 0 0 0 1px #75b316,
        0 0 2px rgba(103, 118, 125, 0.5), 
        0 4px 10px rgba(91, 111, 144, 0.3);
}

.store-slider.ui-widget.ui-widget-content {
    border: 1px solid rgb(206, 212, 218);
}

.ui-slider-handle:hover,
.ui-slider-handle:active,
.ui-slider-handle:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.ui-slider-handle:active {
    background: #89cd20;
    border-color: #75b316;
}

.tippy-content {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.row.filter-row {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: -7px;
  margin-right: -8px;
}

.row.filter-row [class*="col-"] {
  padding-left: 7px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}
</style>


<div class="filter-container">
    <div class="filter-section">
        <div class="h5">По цене</div>
        <div class="slider-wrapper">
            <div id="slider" class="store-slider"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row filter-row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">от</div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control price-input" id="price_from">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">до</div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control price-input" id="price_to">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="filter-section">
        <div class="h5">Мы ценим Вас</div>
        Главное преймущество нашего магазина - это качество товаров и то как мы относимся к нашим клиентам. Если Вы остались не довольны работой наших сотрудников или возникли проблемы с качеством товара, пожалуйста, сходите лесом.
    </div>

</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@2.3.0/dist/tippy.all.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        console.clear();

        var currentValue = {
            from: 1106,
            to: 10000
        }

        var slider = $('#slider').slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 11850,
            values: [currentValue.from, currentValue.to],
            create: function (event, ui) {
                var $slider = $(this);
                var $sliderWrapper = $slider.closest('.store-slider-wrapper');
                var $sliderHandlers = $slider.find('.ui-slider-handle');
                var $sliderHandlersMin = $sliderHandlers.eq(0);
                var $sliderHandlersMax = $sliderHandlers.eq(1);
                var $sliderRange = $slider.find('.ui-slider-range');
                var values = {
                    from: currentValue.from,
                    to: currentValue.to
                }

                $sliderHandlersMin.attr('title', 'от ' + values.from + ' грн');
                $sliderHandlersMax.attr('title', 'до ' + values.to + ' грн');
                $sliderRange
                    .attr('title', values.from + ' - ' + values.to + ' грн')
                    .attr('data-tippy-distance', 15);;

                var tippyOptions = {
                    trigger: 'manual',
                    sticky: true,
                    dynamicTitle: true,
                    hideOnClick: false,
                    arrow: true,
                    arrowType: 'round',
                    animation: 'fade',
                    placement: 'top',
                    livePlacement: false,
                    flipBehavior: [],
                    createPopperInstanceOnInit: true,
                    appendTo: $(this).closest('.filter-section')[0],
                    popperOptions: {
                        modifiers: {
                            // preventOverflow: {
                            //     boundariesElement: $(this).closest('.filter-section')[0],
                            // }
                            computeStyle: {
                                gpuAcceleration: true
                            }
                        },
                    }
                };

                tippy($sliderHandlersMin[0], tippyOptions);
                tippy($sliderHandlersMax[0], tippyOptions);
                tippy($sliderRange[0], tippyOptions);

                updateSliderTooltip($slider, values);
            },
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                var $slider = $(this);
                var $sliderWrapper = $slider.closest('.store-slider-wrapper');
                var values = {
                    from: ui.values[0],
                    to: ui.values[1]
                }

                updateSliderTooltip($slider, values, true);
            }
        });

        function updateSliderTooltip($slider, values, updateInput) {
            if (typeof updateInput === "undefined")
                var updateInput = true;

            var $sliderWrapper = $slider.closest('.store-slider-wrapper');
            var $sliderHandlers = $slider.find('.ui-slider-handle');
            var $sliderHandlersMin = $sliderHandlers.eq(0);
            var $sliderHandlersMax = $sliderHandlers.eq(1);
            var $sliderRange = $slider.find('.ui-slider-range');

            $sliderHandlersMin.attr('title', 'от ' + values.from + ' грн');
            $sliderHandlersMax.attr('title', 'до ' + values.to + ' грн');
            $sliderRange.attr('title', 'от ' + values.from + ' и до ' + values.to + ' грн');

            if (updateInput) {
                $('#price_from').val(values.from);
                $('#price_to').val(values.to);
            }

            setInterval(function () {
                var tooltipMinLeft = getCoords($sliderHandlersMin[0]).left;
                var tooltipMaxLeft = getCoords($sliderHandlersMax[0]).left;

                var tooltipRange = tooltipMaxLeft - tooltipMinLeft;
                var singleTooltip = tooltipRange < 80;

                if (!singleTooltip) {
                    if (!$sliderHandlersMin[0]._tippy.state.visible)
                        $sliderHandlersMin[0]._tippy.show(0);
                    if (!$sliderHandlersMax[0]._tippy.state.visible)
                        $sliderHandlersMax[0]._tippy.show(0);
                    if ($sliderRange[0]._tippy.state.visible)
                        $sliderRange[0]._tippy.hide(0);
                } else {
                    if ($sliderHandlersMin[0]._tippy.state.visible)
                        $sliderHandlersMin[0]._tippy.hide(0);
                    if ($sliderHandlersMax[0]._tippy.state.visible)
                        $sliderHandlersMax[0]._tippy.hide(0);
                    if (!$sliderRange[0]._tippy.state.visible)
                        $sliderRange[0]._tippy.show(0);
                }
            }, 1);
        }

        function updateValues() {
            var from = $('#price_from').val();
            var to = $('#price_to').val();

            updateSliderTooltip(slider, {
                from: from,
                to: to
            }, false);

            slider.slider({
                values: [from, to]
            });
        }

        $('#price_from').on('blur', function () {
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/i, ''));

            if (+$(this).val() > +$('#price_to').val()) {
                $(this).val($('#price_to').val())
            }

            updateValues();
        });

        $('#price_to').on('blur', function () {
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/gi, ''));

            if (+$(this).val() < +$('#price_from').val()) {
                $(this).val($('#price_from').val())
            }

            updateValues();
        });

        function getCoords(elem) {
            var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

            var body = document.body;
            var docEl = document.documentElement;

            var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || docEl.scrollTop || body.scrollTop;
            var scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || docEl.scrollLeft || body.scrollLeft;

            var clientTop = docEl.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0;
            var clientLeft = docEl.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0;

            var top = box.top + scrollTop - clientTop;
            var left = box.left + scrollLeft - clientLeft;

            return { top: Math.round(top), left: Math.round(left) };
        }

    </script>
}
```

**2. Add jquery and jquery-ui in _Layout.cshtml.**

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - signalr_iwa</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/signalr_iwa.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    @* add this line *@
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">signalr_iwa</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <p class="nav navbar-text">Hello, @User.Identity?.Name!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2023 - signalr_iwa - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @* add this line *@
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    @* add this line *@
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**3. Then we can test it**

[image]

Comment: Hi @Limna You can use `jquery-v3.5.js`, I have test it and it works well. And I also tried the code you provided, it also works well. Seems there are other js files cause the error. You should find it out.

Comment: Hi @Limna, you can create a brand new project to test the sample I provided, thanks

Comment: Hi @Jason Pan, I have added `<script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@2.3.0/dist/tippy.all.min.js"></script>` at the end of my `.cshtml` file. And put rest of the `js` code in separate `js` file. And  its reference is added below of the `tippy.all.min.js` reference in the `cshtml` file.
But I'm getting error `Uncaught ReferenceError: tippy is not defined`.

Comment: Hi @Limna , I have already add it in my sample code, like `@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@2.3.0/dist/tippy.all.min.js"></script>`. Please check it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVLEj.png

Comment: Hi @Limna It's impossible, could you try to create a brand new project for testing.

Comment: @Limna We can't find any errors in my console window, right ? I think if you want to solve the issue quickly, you need provide your sample project which can reproduce the issue, I mean delete all the sensitive or business code in your project.

Comment: Hi @Limna, I have a working one in my side, so I recommend you provide a brand new sample without any sensitive information for me investigating, it could save your time,I will check it tomorrow, have a nice day.

Comment: Hi @Limna I am afraid you can’t, you can create a repo in github,again,pls delete all the sensitive information in your project. It could protect your data safety.

Comment: Hi @Limna, I am free now, and I have downloaded it, you can delete the repo now. Will reply you soon

Comment: Hi @Limna, the repo you shared I can't running it in my local. could you create a brand new project which can reproduce the issue for me, tks~

Comment: Can you try this https://github.com/limnadsilva/range-slider

Comment: Hi @Limna, It's order issue, pls check this https://i.imgur.com/BZNOwIX.png

Comment: @Limna Seems the sample not completely, I can't make the sample works as expected, if you need further help, pls let me know. There is no error here https://i.imgur.com/nrA8we3.png

Comment: Hi @Jason Pan, `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>` 
above provided version of `jquery-ui` is not compatible with our `jquery` version `jQuery v3.5.0`. Do you have any other reference of `jquery-ui` that support version `v3.5.0`. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Limna, you can use this one. https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js

Comment: @Limna [Compatibility with recent jQuery versions (up to 3.6): Usage of deprecated jQuery APIs have been removed. jQuery UI 1.13 triggers no jQuery Migrate warnings when running its test suite against jQuery 3.6.0 with jQuery Migrate 3.3.2, i.e. the latest versions at the moment of its release.](https://jqueryui.com/)